# Checkbox select all checkboxes Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

**Here is my problem:**

In PHP Laravel I have a foreach loop that displays messages on the screen including a checkbox. Every message has its own checkbox. I also have a checkbox at the top of all the messages. I would like to assign a function to that checkbox to check all the checkboxes. I know this question has been asked in the past, but unfortunately those answers didn't work for me. Does someone have a solution for me?

I'm using: Laravel, Inspinia, Bootstrap 4

Thanks in advance!

**Here is my code:**

```
@if(count($messages) > 0)
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>

                    //select all checkboxes
                    <th><input type="checkbox" class=""/></th>

                    <th>@sortablelink('title', trans('messages.title'))</th>
                    <th>@sortablelink('sender_user_id', trans('messages.sender'))</th>
                    <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">@sortablelink('created_at', trans('messages.sent_at'))</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach ($messages as $message)
                <tr id="messagesTable">
                    <td><i class="{{ $message->read ? 'far fa-envelope-open' : 'fas fa-envelope' }}"></i></td>

                    //the checkboxes who need to be selected
                    <td class="project-title">
                        <div class="checkbox p1-1"> 
                            <input type="checkbox" id="message_{{$message->id}}" name="message" value="{{$message->id}}">
                            <label for="message_{{$message->id}}"></label>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td class="project-title">
                        <a href="{{ route('messages.read', [$message->id]) }}">{{$message->title}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="project-title">
                        <a href="{{ route('messages.read', [$message->id]) }}">{{ $message->sender ? $message->sender->name : ''}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="project-title d-none d-sm-table-cell">
                        <a href="{{ route('messages.read', [$message->id]) }}">{{$message->created_at->format('d-m-Y H:i')}}</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in `jquery`

**first step**
change this

```
//select all checkboxes
<th><input type="checkbox" class=""/></th>
```

to this

```
//select all checkboxes
<th><input type="checkbox" class="check_all"/></th> //just added a class to this element
```

---

**Second step**
add class_name to all your `<input type="checkbox">`
i mean `<input type="checkbox" id="message_{{$message->id}}" name="message" value="{{$message->id}}">` changed to `<input type="checkbox" id="message_{{$message->id}}" name="message" value="{{$message->id}}" class="custom_name">`

**NOTE:** `be sure that all your checkboxes has one class_name instead the one witch if we click it others checked!`

---

**Third step**
add this in footer

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(".check_all").on("click", function(){
        $(".custom_name").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("checked", true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I HPOE THIS WORKS FOR YOU...

Comment: I get an error on this line `$("input[type='checkbox']).each(function(){` invalid or unexpected token

Comment: You will also need to add how to add jQuery to the project as it is currently unclear if he's already using it.

Comment: @rezash I want to give you an award: brother of the year. Without complaining you answered the question. You rock dude.

Comment: your answer working fine sir .How do un select all checkbox

Comment: @GanesanJ check if `$(".check_all').is(":checked")` then add `false` instead of `true` for unchecking.